# Using multiple PostgreSQL schemas with Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, models, database-schema, schema-design

I have a PostgreSQL database for my Rails application. In the schema named 'public' the main Rails models tables are stored etc. I have created a 'discogs' schema which will have tables with names that are sometimes the same as in the 'public' schema - which is one of the reasons that I'm using schemas to organize this.

How would I setup models from the 'discogs' schema in my app? I will be using Sunspot to let Solr index these models as well. I'm unsure of how you would do this.

Comment: How does one create the non 'public' schema when setting up the database through the db:create rake task? Adding the schema to the template1 database is a possibility. But is there a way to do it as part of the normal rails/rake development process?

Comment: @TsenYing [There is pg_power gem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18227887/673826) for that as one option. Its [home is here](https://github.com/TMXCredit/pg_power). It hasn't been updated for 2 yrs though. Another option might be to write *create* rake task in *db* namespace and add your stuff there.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

PostgreSQL adapter schema_search_path in database.yml does solve your problem?

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf-8
  database: solidus
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  schema_search_path: "discogs,public"
```

Or, you can to specify different connections for each schema:

```
public_schema:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf-8
  database: solidus
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  schema_search_path: "public"

discogs_schema:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf-8
  database: solidus
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  schema_search_path: "discogs"
```

After each connection defined, create two models:

```
class PublicSchema < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :public_schema
end

class DiscoGsSchema < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :discogs_schema
end
```

And, all your models inherit from the respective schema:

```
class MyModelFromPublic < PublicSchema
  set_table_name :my_table_name
end

class MyOtherModelFromDiscoGs < DiscoGsSchema
  set_table_name :disco
end
```

Comment: Looks like you should add self.abstract_class = true to *Schema classes to avoid non-existing tables troubles.

Comment: The config `schema_search_path:` is crucial, if You leave it and use only `self.table_name = 'discogs.disco'` than all seems to work...except `database_cleaner`. It uses `schema_search_path` for to get list of tables from schemas. I ommit this and records keep stocking in ommited schema tables between test runs.

Comment: I have tried the same but I'm not able to access the active storage record of **DiscoGsSchema** 
Example: **User** table is present only in PublicSchema and then I'm trying to execute `User.first.image` and it's still checking in PublicSchema, not in DiscoGsSchema. but however, I'm getting a User record from PublicSchema but not an Active storage image stored in S3.

Kindly check the link for a detailed description
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74919527/how-to-support-active-storage-in-multi-schema)

Answer (score 20):

The correct one for rails 4.2 is as:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'myschema.foo'
end
```

More info -http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D

Answer (score 15):

In migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute 'CREATE SCHEMA settings'
    create_table 'settings.users' do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table 'settings.users'
    execute 'DROP SCHEMA settings'
  end

end
```

Optional in model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name 'settings.users'
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Just do

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'myschema.foo'
end
```

Comment: Deprecate `set_table_name` in favour of `self.table_name=` https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0b72a04

Answer (score 12):

Because `set_table_name` was removed, and it was replaced by `self.table_name`.

I think you should code follow as:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name =  'myschema.foo'
end
```

Answer (score 5):

method `set_table_name` has been remove. `self.table_name` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  primary_abstract_class

  # Set schema
  def self.schema(schema)
    self.table_name = "#{schema}.#{self.name.tableize}"
  end
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  schema :myschema
end
```