# Connect to existing Postgresql database with ActiveRecord without rails

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I am not using rails, and I'm trying to use ActiveRecord to make it easier to work with an existing database. This is just a script so I have no database.yml or any other files. I've set up my database connection using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:    'postgresql',
  host:       'thehosthere',
  database:   'management',
  username:   'management_readonly',
  password:   '',
  port:       '5432'
)
```

I'm not really familiar with databases, so I'll just state what I know about this one. There are quite a few schemas. The schema I'm interested in is the management schema that has the table "host". I've created a class Host in the script like this:

```
class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "host"
end
```

I'm then trying to pull all rows that match the criteria with this query and to store it into an array.

```
servers = Host.where(:realm => 'stage', :status => 'UP').pluck(:hostname)
```

but I am getting this error every single time.

```
 ruby environments_are_okDev.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec': PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "host" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"host"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid,
a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"host"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_no_cache'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in `block in exec_query'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:915:in `column_definitions'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:174:in `columns'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `default'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:247:in `column_names'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:60:in `block in method_missing'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:270:in `scoping'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:60:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:152:in `block in pluck'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:151:in `map!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:151:in `pluck'
        from environments_are_okDev.rb:51:in `run'
        from environments_are_okDev.rb:97:in `<main>'
```

I don't really understand why this is happening, so I tried to see what the database looks like with this command `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` but all I got was an empty array. I'm not sure what could be happening. I'm obviously doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what. Keep in mind, this is all in a single file script.

Edit:

So I can see the schemas if I use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_names`. This gives me an array `=> ["db_stats", "management", "management_audit", "public"]` Using pgadmin, I know that the table I want is in management, so how do I access that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using multiple PostgreSQL schemas with Rails models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806284/using-multiple-postgresql-schemas-with-rails-models)

Comment: Maybe try adding `schema_search_path: 'management'` to your call to `establish_connection`?

Comment: Seriously, use another ORM. Any other ORM. ActiveRecord is the worst part of Rails. As someone who approaches it from the database side of things it's ... scary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `schema_search_path` when you call `establish_connection`:

```ruby
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:    'postgresql',
  host:       'thehosthere',
  database:   'management',
  username:   'management_readonly',
  password:   '',
  port:       5432,
  schema_search_path: 'management' # <-- ???
)
```

Comment: I had figured out I could use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path right before you posted this, but I didn't realize I could put it in the establish_connection method. Thanks!

Comment: @maerics: I have the same problem, i had tried your solution but it didn't work for me can you please post me any other alternative for this

Comment: @anusha You could create a before_filter method and put the logic there that changes the schema_search_path