# Rails create task or model to update the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, schema

I have a list of tables(Postgres database), and i want to create a rake task or method i do not know which one will be better to change the schema for existing table.

I have done a lot of googling and i found that mostly multi schema are used for multi tenant applications, currently i would have two schema alone and use it in db like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806284/using-multiple-postgresql-schemas-with-rails-models)

I have a list of tables like user profile projects and more, what i would like to do is update the schema while rake db:drop or rake db:migrate

Example:

User and profile stays in public schema
and the task should create a new schema say "dashboard" and move the project table to dashboard.

How do i create a task or method to update the schema while drop and migrate?