# Rails does not add new tables to schema.rb in non public schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a new table via rails migration in Postgres in a new schema (name - "concluded")

```
class CreateWeeklyLeaderboard < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute('create schema concluded')
    create_table('concluded.weekly_leaderboard') do |t|
      t.date :week_start_date
      t.references :user
      t.integer :rank
      t.integer :points
      t.timestamps null: true
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table('concluded.weekly_leaderboard')
    execute('drop schema concluded')
  end
end
```

## Update

If you add your schema to your database configuration, you will get the table definition in schema.rb

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: duggout
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: pass
  schema_search_path: public, concluded
```

The create_table in schema.rb appears like below:

```
create_table "weekly_leaderboard", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.date     "week_start_date"
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.integer  "rank"
   t.integer  "points"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
 end
```

As you see, the schema name does not appear in this file. How to ensure schema name is present in schema.rb for non public tables?

This is important because in our test machines (or CI agents), we do `rake schema:load` instead of `rake db:migrate` as recommended by Rails. In such cases, these tables get created in the public schema instead of 'concluded' schema.

Comment: can you share your database configuration? 
You have to enable schemas in configurations
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806284/using-multiple-postgresql-schemas-with-rails-models

Comment: @MihhailSidorin Checking it..

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8838881/1826279) mostly covers multiple schema setup.

Comment: @MihhailSidorin schema.rb get the create definition now, but without the schema name

Comment: I think it is specific of unified approach for different databases. Let's say we will have Sqlite database, we won't be able to set schema there, while with "magical" set of models schema will work even for Sqlite. In given case inheritance from different AR base classes will always define which schema to query. You can rollback to `SQL` version of schema if you want database specific SQL schema dump stored.

Comment: This will have one potential issue, when we do `rake schema:load` the table gets created in the public schema not in my expected schema

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran , had u any luck fixing this issue? Because I now have the same issue.

Comment: @RoyPhilips Nope.